# i am trying to run a shell script from jsp but i am getting Ljava.lang.string error

Tags: java, jsp, shell

I have the code in this way:

```
<% Process p;
 String[] cmd =  "Z:\\walmart\\environment.sh";

 try {    
   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
   StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();

   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream)));     

   while (input.readLine() != null)  
   {
     s.append(input.readLine() + "\n");      
   } 

   System.out.println(s.toString()); 

 }
 catch (IOException e) {  
    System.err.println("Failed to read & or start "); 
 }  

%>
```

Comment: Next time, please just paste your code as it is in the editor, select it all and click on the `{}` button. Make sure it looks nice in the preview. **And post the actual error message.**

Answer (score 1):

This

```
String[] cmd = "Z:\walmart\environment.sh";
```

should be

```
String[] cmd = {"Z:\walmart\environment.sh"};
```

It is an array of string. Not an array of char or a string!

Comment: Don't you also need to escape the `\\` in the filename?

Comment: Yes, you're right. The escaping actually was there in the poster's code, the lack of code formatting hid it.

Answer (score 1):

1 - I think you need to escape the backslashes in your file path and make it an array:

```
String[] cmd = {"Z:\\walmart\\environment.sh"};
```

2 - Add a generic error handler to find out your error:

```
catch (Throwable th)     {  
     System.err.println("Error:"); 
     th.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Comment: the script i should run is in my local windows and the path is "Z:\walmart\environment.sh". I want to run this script through the jsp code . is is possible..? pls help me..

Comment: Only if your jsp is executing on the same machine (Windows). It seems you are trying to run a UNIX (.sh) script on Windows? That won't work unless you are using Cygwin, etc.